# configure binary sensor from mqtt

Tags: mqtt, sensors, home-assistant

I have zway controller with MQTT client enabled and binary sensors which publish state to mqtt topic.

zway95/data/ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12

```
{
  "creationTime": 1587157138,
  "creatorId": 1,
  "customIcons": {},
  "deviceType": "sensorBinary",
  "firmware": "3.80",
  "h": 1979762458,
  "hasHistory": false,
  "id": "ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12",
  "location": 3,
  "locationName": "Коридор",
  "manufacturer": "Shenzhen Neo Electronics Co., Ltd",
  "metrics": {
    "probeTitle": "Motion",
    "scaleTitle": "",
    "icon": "motion",
    "level": "off",
    "title": "Движение - Коридор",
    "isFailed": false
  },
  "nodeId": 9,
  "order": {
    "rooms": 0,
    "elements": 0,
    "dashboard": 0,
    "room": 2
  },
  "permanently_hidden": false,
  "probeType": "motion",
  "product": "",
  "tags": [],
  "technology": "Z-Wave",
  "visibility": true,
  "updateTime": 1643685077
}
```

zway95/state/ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12

```
off
```

or

```
on
```

Also I have such config in HA

```
binary_sensor:
  - platform: mqtt
    state_topic: "zway95/state/ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12"
    name: "testmotion"
    device_class: "motion"
    payload_on: "true"
    payload_off: "false"
    availability_template: "{{ value_json.metrics.isFailed }}"
    availability:
      - topic: "zway95/data/ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12"
    payload_available: false
    payload_not_available: true
    json_attributes_topic: "zway95/data/ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12"
```

In HA sensor looks like unavailble and attributes are missing

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: I solve tracking problem by adding
    payload_on: "on"
    payload_off: "off"

but I still need assistance with tracking availability of sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand the [home assistant documentation](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/binary_sensor.mqtt/) `availability_template` is intended to be used along with `availability_topic`. So either go for

```
availability_template: "{{ value_json['metrics']['isFailed'] }}"
availability_topic: "zway95/data/ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12"
payload_available: false
payload_not_available: true
```

or

```
 availability:
   - topic: "zway95/data/ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12"
     payload_available: false
     payload_not_available: true
     value_template: "{{ value_json['metrics']['isFailed'] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working config:

```
binary_sensor:
  - platform: mqtt
    state_topic: "zway95/state/ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12"
    name: "testmotion"
    device_class: "motion"
    payload_on: "on"
    payload_off: "off"
    availability_topic: "zway95/data/ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12"
    availability_template: "{{ value_json.metrics.isFailed }}"
    payload_available: false
    payload_not_available: true
    json_attributes_topic: "zway95/data/ZWayVDev_zway_9-0-48-12"
```